# iOS: YAJL framework not detected

Tags: ios, objective-c, yajl

I have an old objective-c project. In the framework group I have different frameworks such as `CoreDate`, `UIKit`... and the `YAJL` one. When I try to build my project I get this error:

```
ld: file too small (length=0) file '/Users/userName/MyApp/MyAppContent/Libraries/YAJL.framework/YAJL' for architecture i386
```

The `YAJL` is in the `Frameworks` folder and not in the `Libraries`. It has the same level as `MyApp` folder.

I searched about the error `file too small (length=0)` I tried all the solutions (the most popular is to clean and rebuild the project) but I'm getting the same error.

In the `Build setting` -> `Framework search path`: I found that I have "$(SRCROOT)/MyApp/Libraries", if I remove it I get `YAJL/YAJL.h file not found` and `ld: file too small (length=0) file '/Users/userName/MyApp/MyAppContent/Libraries/YAJL.framework/YAJL' for architecture i386`.

When I add `"$(SRCROOT)/Frameworks/YAJL.Framework"` I get: `-F No directory found Frameworks`

Can anyone tell me please how can I solve this issue?